# Outlook 2016 Stuck Updating Inbox

Tags: microsoft-office-365, outlook-2016

Around every 15 minutes my outlook client will get stuck updating some kind of folder and not allow emails to send\receive. Closing outlook and reopening will send the email in my outbox and new emails come in. Rinse and repeat all day.

- I've gotten rid of the email profile.
- Uninstalled Outlook 2016 and tried Outlook 2019 (same problem) and now back on Outlook 2016.
- Disabled all add-ons except Microsoft Exchange Add-in.
- Uninstalled my anti-virus.
- Disabling Windows Firewall.

Comment: What email server are you using? Sounds like the issue is there, not with your email client.

Comment: Using office 365 for the email server. I actually just installed the latest update and haven't had any problems so far. I'll call it a win if it goes the whole day without getting stuck.

Comment: The update didn't work. I've been dealing with this for the last year still and don't have a fix. Someone in my department has the same exact issue but everyone else in the company seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the solution to this problem. I disabled IPv6 on my network adapter and that seemed to do the trick.